# What do I enter in the API Username and API password for the Commerce CardPointe module so that it works with Clover Connect?

Tags: commerce, 10

I have installed the Commerce CardPointe module in Drupal 10 and have a merchant account with Clover. The module asks me to input the API Username, API password, merchant ID and Site. I know the Merchant ID, but unsure what to enter in the API Username, API password and Site fields. I called technical support but they were only aware of an API token - which sounds different from API Username and password. Any help here would really be appreciated! New to Drupal and trying to figure this out for a client ASAP.
Thank you!!

Comment: Hey Jeff, if you want to reach out via the contact form at centarro.io, happy to help. It does look like the docs have changed since we wrote the readme, but we have contacts at Clover who we can likely connect you to for support with your account.

Comment: Absolutely - will do, thanks Ryan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who find this later, it turns out you need to get the API username and password from technical support when you setup your CardPointe account. This will be different from the relationship you may have with Clover for POS sales established through your bank.